# PivotTable con campo adicional Eloquent Laravel 5.6 Mass Assigment Protection

Tags: php, laravel-5

a la hora de utilizar pivot tables con campos adicionales, no me permite crear el registro ya que debo declararlo como fillable... como podria declarar el campo adicional como fillable?

Supongamos que tenemos la tabla Estudiante y la tabla Curso y una pivot table Curso_Estudiante

```
Table: Curso_Estudiante
----------------------------------------
| curso_id | estudiante_id | descripcion
```

curso_id y estudiante_id son añadido sin problema pero ele campo descripcion no puedo hacerle attach() ya que debo declararlo como fillable en alguna parte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora mismo no sabria decirte si es posible , asignar un fillable a los campos pivotes , pero una solución sencilla y lo que yo uso seria algo como esto.

```
$estudiante = Estudiante::create($estudianteData);
$curso = Curso::create($cursoData);
$estudiante->curso()->attach($curso->id , ['descripcion' => $request->descripcion]);
```

Comment: eso funciona de maravilla, el problema lo tengo cuando quiero hacer $estudiante->curso()->attach(["curso_id" => $curso->id , "descripcion" => $request->descripcion]);

Comment: gracias solucionado